# JavaScript click on the link/button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hi guys how would you click this link/Button I cant get any method to work, i have tried:

```
$('btn btn-large btn-info btn-embossed').children('a').click();

$('visit-trigger').trigger('click');

document.querySelector("visit-trigger").click();
```

I have tried all the names and class I could find not only the : visit-trigger class.

[Website if you want to try your self](https://gleam.io/xIxq9/ginger-beyond-the-crystal-giveaway-from-video-chums)

```
 <div class="expandable ng-scope" ng-include="entryMethodView(entry_method)">
    <form class="entry_details compact-box form-compact ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope" name="entryDetailsForm">
    <div class="form-compact__content center">
    <div class="form-compact__part">
    <p>Click here to ensure you are subscribed:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-compact__part">
    <p class="visit-trigger">
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-info btn-embossed" ng-href="https://youtube.com/user/videochumstube?sub_confirmation=1" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/user/videochumstube?sub_confirmation=1">
    <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
    &nbsp;
    Subscribe here
    </a>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("btn-embossed")[0].click()` should work.

Comment: Worked like charm thanks @aquaman ;)

Answer (score 2):

`visit-trigger` is a class so use class selector

```
$('.visit-trigger').trigger('click');
//-^-------here
```

or

```
$('.btn-embossed').click(); // to fire the click event of `a`
```

Anyways most important part is use proper selectors. `.` for class, `#` for ids and so on.